# Deploying Vaadin application with SQLite

Tags: java, database, sqlite, vaadin

I have a problem with deploying Vaadin application on server. The problem is with database connection.
This is my function to connect with database:

```
private void initConnectionPool() {
        try {

            connectionPool = new SimpleJDBCConnectionPool(
                    "org.sqlite.JDBC",
            "jdbc:sqlite:"+System.getProperty("user.home")+"\\IWM\\ERegister\\WebContent\\Database\\iwmDataBase.db", "", "");
            System.out.println("=======================================");
            System.out.println(connectionPool.toString());
            System.out.println("=======================================");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

After deploying I can observe this: 
http://vosky.pl:8080/ERegister/

I see that the problem is with database path, but I have no clue how to make correct path. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2):

Your server seems to be running some kind of Linux or Unix.

So path delimiters are forward slash and not backward slash.

To be platform neutral you could use the File.separator instead of forward/backward slashes.

private void initConnectionPool() {
        try {

```
        connectionPool = new SimpleJDBCConnectionPool(
                "org.sqlite.JDBC",
        "jdbc:sqlite:"+System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+"IWM"+File.separator+"ERegister"+File.separator+"WebContent"+File.separator+"Database"+File.separator+"iwmDataBase.db", "", "");
        System.out.println("=======================================");
        System.out.println(connectionPool.toString());
        System.out.println("=======================================");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```